# How to make two vectors orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

From [my question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47541/constructing-an-orthogonal-polynomial-regression-model) on CV, I need to find a way to make my two vectors orthogonal. They are:

$${\bf{v}} = \pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 } \hspace{1.5cm} {\bf{w}} = \pmatrix{0.25 \\ 0.0625 \\ 0 \\ 0.0625 \\ 0.25}$$

What I (think) I need is the step that makes these two vectors orthogonal and I think that will give me my orthogonal regression model.

But how do I do this? It's not Gram-Schmidt is it?

EDIT:

1) Fixed spelling of Gram-Schmidt thanks to the comment.

2) Basically, for my regression model to be orthogonal, I need all the sum of all the linear terms to be 0 and the sum of all the quadratic terms to be 0. The vector ${\bf{w}}$ is all the $x_i^2$ terms in matrix form. What I need is effectively the dot product of ${\bf{v \cdot w' }} = 0$, where ${\bf{w'}}$ is basically ${\bf{w}}$ transformed in some way such that the sum of all these new terms equal $0$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you want two orthogonal vectors which form a basis of the subspace generated by the two you have given?

Comment: @Mark Bennet No, I want the step that makes these two vectors orthogonal, if that either a) makes sense, or b) is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you are looking for [Gram-Schmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Let ${\bf v_1 } \equiv {\bf v }$ and ${\bf v_2 } \equiv {\bf w } - (\frac{{\bf v } \cdot  {\bf w}}{\bf v \cdot v}) {\bf v}$ if you only want them to be orthogonal to each other.

Note evaluating ${\bf v_1} \cdot {\bf v_2} = {\bf v} \cdot {\bf w} - \frac{{\bf v} \cdot {\bf w}}{{\bf v} \cdot {\bf v}} ({\bf v} \cdot {\bf v}) = 0$.  Any vector you could get with $a {\bf v} + b {\bf w}$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$, you can reach with $\alpha {\bf v_1} + \beta {\bf v_2}$ for some scalar $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Again if two vectors aren't initially orthogonal, you can't do any rotation or change of basis to make them not orthogonal (as orthogonality is independent of choice of basis).  You have to fundamentally change the vectors.

Comment: Oh wait, I don't think my question will work then will it? Because it will give me the vector that is orthogonal to ${\bf{v}}$ but not in the form that I need it to put it in my regression model. My model basically has to have some $\sum (x_i^2 + Ax_i + B) = 0$ and I want to work out this $A, B$.